# What happens to the APNS Certificate when revoking the distribution Certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am new to the APNS certificate thing. My question is a old developer lost our Private Key which we used for several in-house (ad-hoc) applications, and an application we use to push out applications and policies to users. I know that the only way to get the private key is to revoke the certificate and then generate a new one and re-sign all the internal applications and re-deploy with the new cert. My only concern is what happens to the application that uses APNS, does this still use the distribution certificate from our apple account, or will this not be affected when we revoke the distribution certificate?

Answer (score 4):

The push certificate is not part of the provisioning profile. It has nothing to do with the client (the app), only your server's connection to APNS is affected.

Comment: So, what does that mean? If the cert is revoked then the servers ability to push notifications is broken?