# Are iOS APNS certificates invalidated when the distribution profile is replaced?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087983/what-happens-to-the-apns-certificate-when-revoking-the-distribution-certificate) asks something similar, but I want to qualify a detail.

I understand that the APNS certificate is unrelated to the provisioning profile, but does this also mean that the APNS servers will continue to accept push notifications sent via an 'orphaned' APNS certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about replacing a distribution provisioning profile, not cerificate.

This is not a case of an "orphaned" APNS certificate - the certificate was created by some valid identity and should still be valid. The only thing that could go wrong in this scenario is if you cancelled APNS support for the App ID you're using - since this isn't the case and you're just replacing the provisioning profile (which will be attached to the push-enabled app ID), nothing is bound to break.

Hope this helps, good luck